# Stripe: Best approach for intermittent invoicing?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment

I have (say) a service that makes widgets. For any given customer, some days they may order 100, some days they many order none. Most customers, most days, will be none. There is no recurring charge - I just charge for widgets. I'd like to invoice them daily.

What's the best way to set this up with Stripe?

I can add detached `InvoiceItem`s to the `Customer` as they purchase widgets easily enough. But how should I trigger the invoice?

This seems straightforward with a Subscription - there's a `pending_invoice_item_interval` that looks ideally suited for this. But I'm not doing any kind of recurring billing. I don't want to fill their history with a bunch of $0 invoices. I guess I could make an annual $0 plan to cut down on the # of weird $0 invoices? This seems hacky.

I guess I could run a job that manually batches up all the pending invoice items for each customer every night. Is that the recommended solution? This feels like the kind of thing that Stripe should be doing... am I missing something in the API?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Metered billing might work well for you here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/metered-billing, and maybe threshold billing: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/metered-billing/thresholds

Comment: While relevant to my interests, those (along with pending_invoice_item_interval) are part of the "start a subscription" solution I tried to describe above. Is that the right answer? Start a subscription even though there is no specific regular invoice?

Comment: You could use that on a daily frequency in conjunction with a yearly $0 subscription I guess?  That's an interesting idea.  I think that a daily metered solution also fits here, as long as they often order stuff.  Really depends what best fits your business.